# What is the easiest way to extend the vertices along the edge just like vertex slide function (Shortcut G -> G)

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

Just like sliding the vertices along the edges by using vertex slide, I want to "extend" the vertices along the edge vector in a easy way. There are a lot of ways to do like save edge direction vector and use, scale the edge etc... but what would be the easiest and fastest way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Vertex slide* is easiest.
Just disable Clamp and you can slide as far as you want :)

Shortcut: <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
Clamp shortcut: <kbd>C</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Wow, didn't know the option. Thank you!